# Show that someone is working on a solution to my question

Tags: feature-request

I would like to see a flag (or counter?) where people can indicate that they are currently working on an answer for my question. If I know that several people are busy in finding a solution for my problem, I would rather not accept any of the first proposals because I know that there might come something even better a couple of hours or days later.

Comment: Why so many down votes? It is not about not accepting fast answers? It is about giving credit to those wo need more time for answering because they provide a more comprehensive solution. If the faster answers are better, they will of course still be accepted.

Comment: Downvotes are a bit different on Meta. You're offering a request for a feature. It seems that most people think this is a bad idea. It's nothing personal.

Comment: From the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta): *On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself.*.

Comment: Ok. Than the case is clear :) I had such a feature in another Q&A site some years ago and I found it quite useful. But this was just my personal point of view. If the majority opinion is that it is not useful here, I can of course life with that :)

Comment: You do understand you can always unaccept an answer, and an accepted answer, in no way prevents people from submitting a better answer.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But I do not really like to unaccept an answer that has solved my problem. But that's just me...

Answer (score 8):

Or..

Just wait. Really. People are *going* to understand if you wait a day or two before picking an answer. Or if you find an answer is better.

In fact, I recommend you *not* pick this as the correct answer, until you've seen a few more. I can wait.

You can use the time to test current possible answers, comment appropriately if there's *small* tweaks or issues - don't move the goalposts of course, or improve your question somewhat.

Comment: That's true. However, it is still of interest to me if someone is working on my problem or not...

Comment: And that's a thing tho. The actual window where someone is typing out his answer is *very* small. On occasion I've sat on a question for an extended period of time, and then I get hit over the head with a flash of insight. Or I start writing a question, get called away to help with something then come back... Or its something I know, I write it in 5 minutes from memory, and its done.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few things I had like to say on your proposal:

- Never accept an answer quickly. Wait for at least a few hours to let other answers come in. The first might not necessary be the best one, so keep your question open for a while to let the community to post an answer or judge the existing answers (maybe there is a catch you didn't see).
- You can change the accepted answer any time. Some users might not like you for changing the accepted answer, but they will have to live with that. Even if a better answer comes in a year after asking, that answer can be marked as accepted. Nothing forces you to stick with your first choice.

These points make your feature request effectively useless.

Comment: Ok. But as mentioned below, the other aspect is, that I know that one or more people are currently working on my problem.

Comment: *I am working on your issue now!* Don't expect an answer ever since I forgot about you now already... Got the point?

Answer (score 2):

I've many times changed my mind about answering questions, so if there was such a feature to promise someone that I'll answer their questions, I'd have broken those promises countless times.

I **strongly disagree** with the proposal.

In the meantime, you already have the "star" button to bookmark a question. So if your question received a bunch of stars, then probably there is a better chance that you'll get a good answer to it, because maybe someone out there wanted to write up an answer later. But there's no guarantee though.