# Warn a user about to delete a question if someone is writing an answer?

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions

Today I posted a question, but half an hour later thought better of it and chose to delete it. It had only 6 views and no interaction (e.g. comments or votes) so I don't think someone was typing an answer. But otherwise I would definitely not delete it, since I'd just have wasted that person's time.

Could the system somehow detect that and add something like this to the confirmation dialog?

> Someone is writing an answer right now. Please consider not deleting this question!

Comment: While the site might be able to check if someone has a draft saved for an answer (and that feature is imperfect), that would miss anyone who was doing research or writing up their answer is a separate text editor (which I do often)

Comment: Some related questions: [Feature “There are n users working on an answer” notification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212188/) [Show that someone is working on a solution to my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295622/) [add a marker (like star) to questions indicating “I'm working on it”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73276/) etc.

Comment: *I* would never write random characters just to tell someone that I was working on an answer to their question. Quite frankly, I don't really care if they know if I'm working on an answer or not, and if they delete the Q I'm fine with that. See the last question I linked for a proposal similar to your "perhaps push a button" line.

Comment: Why not wait 1/2 an hour before posting each question after you've written it, then if you change your mind you can just not post it in the first place.

Comment: @RobertLongson I mean... The existence of the verb "regret" has a meaning.

Comment: @bobble there is also the opposite problem - if somebody uses the answer text box as a scratch pad even if they don't intend to post an answer. That's what I do often - if I need to do editing on the question, I sometimes copy it over in the answer box, format it, then hit Edit and paste the formatted part. That way I don't have to keep the edit dialog open and potentially scrap my changes if any other edit comes in.

Comment: It happens.  No big deal.

Answer (score -1):

One can more or less clearly convey that message by bookmarking the question, even if temporarily. [This idea was taken from a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73276/add-a-marker-like-star-to-questions-indicating-im-working-on-it#comment176737_73276).

Comment: Bookmarks don't show on live refresh, so someone who didn't refresh the page won't see it.

Comment: Bookmarks don't mean "I want to answer this question", nor are they supposed to be strictly positive endorsements. They are neutral. That's the reason they were *renamed* from "Favourites" to "Bookmarks" - many people misinterpreted a question being "favourited" for "this is a good question". In fact, bookmearks are used to...bookmark a question. Sometimes because it's interesting, sometimes just to read it later, sometimes because it needs to be deleted but time has to pass for that to be available. Bookmarking doesn't convey intent to answer or indeed support for the question.

Comment: @VLAZ That may be true, however pretty surely the overall chance is that it indicates something good about your question. I don't think this is an ideal solution, but apparently what we have so far.

Comment: I'd avoid attaching meaning to functionality when there is no such meaning as part of the functionality. If somebody bookmarks a question in order to delete it later, it makes no sense to prevent earlier deletion.

Comment: @VLAZ Well, me too, but that's what he have for today. By the way, its symbol a bookmark with a little star... I think we'll agree that a star usually conveys that something is good. See e.g. Github stars.

Comment: ...the symbol for favourites was a star. And *again*, that feature was literally renamed from "favourites" to "bookmarks" (and the icon changed) with the explicit purpose to make it more neutral. Because we used to get a lot of people going "Why was my question downvoted/deleted/closed/etc when it was also favourited". Favouriting is *not* a necessarily positive endorsement. It's neutral. But it *looked* like it was positive. Hence the rename and rebranding to avoid that confusion. You're now trying to inject it back again.

Comment: [Favorites are now known as Bookmarks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347558)

Comment: Changing from favorites to bookmarks is not enough when you keep a star icon. Write halt in the green light of the semaphore and go in the red light and you'll see it won't end up well, even though colors themselves convey no meaning.

Comment: I don't even get your point any more. I explained that there most definitely are people who are *not* using bookmarks as a positive endorsement. Are you trying to convince me that I'm wrong or that they are wrong for doing that?

Comment: @VLAZ My point is: It does not matter what the bookmark is supposed to mean or what Stack Exchange wants it to mean. What matters is how people use it. Despite changing the name from favorite to bookmark, the bookmark symbol **still contains a star**. Just look at it. Do you dispute that a star usually conveys something is good?

Comment: "*What matters is how people use it.*" and they don't use it strictly for content they support. Great, so we agree that bookmarks are not a good signifier that a question is supported. Case closed.

Comment: But they use it mostly for content they support. And even in the unlikely chance someone bookmarked the question for another reason, the asker simply interpreting that as "I should not delete the question" would not hurt. Case closed.

Comment: "*But they use it mostly for content they support.*" [citation needed]

Comment: I've been in this forum long enough to be able to notice that bookmarks are mostly used for interesting questions. I hope you aren't pretending not to notice just for the sake of your point. Just look at your own bookmarks. I have raised additional arguments. If you need more than that, then I wonder what would it be. A poll "how do you use bookmarks"? We apparently don't have one. But let's pretend I agree with you that most people do not actually use bookmarks for good questions. How would this harm my proposal? Looks like it wouldn't.

Comment: "*Just look at your own bookmarks*" the ones you *currently see*? That doesn't account for the bookmarks I've had and were deleted and/or I bookmarked temporarily, came back to later, acted on and unbookmarked. "*A poll "how do you use bookmarks"? We apparently don't have one.*" there has been a user research which I've linked you to. "*How would this harm my proposal?*" two things: 1. Bookmarking *with intent to close/delete* should not prevent closure/deletion. It's actively harming curation. 2. Your pre-suppose your proposal is even needed. I really don't think it is.

Comment: "There has been a user research which I've linked you to." I could not find it. On the contrary, lots of comments to that post suggest it was a pointless thing to "fix". "'. Bookmarking with intent to close/delete should not prevent closure/deletion." It really wouldn't, it would only delay it *if* the asker interpreted it as a good sign. "2. Your pre-suppose your proposal is even needed. I really don't think it is." You're certainly right there given my question scored -10.